# CefSharp how to Simulate a click return results

Tags: c#, .net, cefsharp

I'm playing with `CefBrowser` in C# and I'd like to know how to simulate clicking each HTML element with the class `ClickMe` and return the InnerHTML to C# WantedInnerHtml?

In the proper page the contents of WantedInnerHtml is loaded via an AJAX call

**Code in C#**

```
// press button once page is fully loaded
private void toolStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    string script = @"
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('ClickMe');
    for (var i=0;i<el.length; i++) {
        alert(document.getElementsByClassName('WantedInnerHtml')[0].innerHTML); 
        return ocument.getElementsByClassName('WantedInnerHtml')[0].innerHTML;
        el[i].click();

    }
    }";
    string HtmlResults =  FindImages(script);
}

private string FindImages(string script)
{
    chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        var response = x.Result;
        if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
        {
            dynamic result = response.Result;
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    });
    return string.Empty;
 }
```

**Mock HTML**

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>

<p><div class="ClickMe">Click ME

</div><div class="ClickMe">Click ME

</div></p>

<div class="WantedInnerHtml"><p>
I want this
</p>

</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I've been playing with this today it seems you can only return once not multiply times in a loop

Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Use an asynchronous event handler see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a71a3b04-b19b-4ff6-8f21-2c960c25e397/how-can-i-call-asynchronous-method-in-an-event-handler?forum=csharpgeneral for an example.  Don't use ContinueWith also revise your JavaScript,  it doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: The [FAQs](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CallJSWithResult) suggest ContinueWith ? Please see edit

Comment: It's just an example that's easy to copy and paste. Based on the sample you've provided I'm suggesting a different approach.  As it stands your FindImages function will always return an empty string. Yes you can only return once in a loop, this is the expected JavaScript behaviour,  not specific to CefSharp.

Comment: I meant it appears you can only return one item. not iterate over the loop returning each time. I'm unclear how  an asynchronous event handler could work

Comment: Create an array and add your results to that. Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map if that makes things easier.  Await the call to EvaluateScriptAsync instead of ContinueWith.